# How to send an array from karate feature to Java method?

Tags: karate

We have a java method which accept one String and an array of String:

```
public static void foo(String bar, String... parts){
    modify parameters...
}
```

We would like to send parameters from karate feature:

```
* def temp = JavaClass.foo(bar, part1, part2)
```

It works, but only bar and part2 are sent to foo method. How we can send an array of Strings from karate feature, smth like

```
* def temp = JavaClass.foo(bar, [part1, part2])
```

Sorry if we didn't see the issue in official github repo. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the parts argument as a Java list, it should work then.

`public static void foo(String bar, List<String> parts){`